# Uniformly most powerful test in poisson

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution, inference, statistical-power

This is example in Hogg and Craig's book page  254

[image]

I have shown that the best critical region is   $\sum X_i>=3$.

I don't understand why, after finding  $\sum X_i>=3$ is the best critical region they go onto do   [image]

Since when finding if it is the uniformly most powerful test
[image]

is equivalent to  $\sum X_i>=3$, and this is the critical region for testing for **each** simple hypothesis in $H_1$ and therefore from here can't I say that this is a uniformly most powerful test.

Have they done it like this because since Poisson distribution is discrete we can't find critical value  so that Pr(type 1 error) is **exactly** equal to significance level. But in this case isn't the critical value selected so that size=largest possible values **less** than significance level. So in that case shouldn't the best critical region be, $\sum X_i>=4$

Comment: Your supposition is correct; they have done this because the Poisson is discrete, so we can't find a critical value such that P(type 1 error) is exactly equal to the significance level, except for the significance levels equal to P(type 1 error) at some critical value.  Note, however, that in the second part, they introduce a pre-specified $\alpha = 0.05$.   Since the test with $Y \geq 3$ has P(type 1 error) = 0.08,  it won't do any more.  Instead, you have to go up to $Y \geq 4$ to get P(type 1 error) $\leq$ 0.05.  You will note that in the second line of your second quoted block, they use 4.

Comment: @Jbowman that looks to me like it would be a good answer

Comment: @jbowman Thank you. So at $\alpha=0.05$ is the uniformly most powerful test $\sum X_i>=4 $ or $\sum X_i>=3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Converted and expanded from a comment):

As you suspected, they have done this because the Poisson is discrete, so, except for critical values such that the probability of a type I error is equal to the significance level, we won't be able to match the target $\alpha$ exactly.  In this situation, we try to find a region with the largest probability of type I error less than $\alpha$, in this case, $< 0.05$.  Since $\sum X_i \geq 3$ as a region has a probability of 0.08, it won't do; we need a smaller region.  $\sum X_i \geq 4$ has a probability of 0.019, which is less than 0.05, so it works.